# AWS Glue Limit Input Size

Tags: python, apache-spark, dataframe, aws-glue

I would like to test my AWS Glue PySpark job with a small subset of the data available. How can this be achieved?

My first try was to convert the Glue dynamic frame to a spark data frame, and use the take(n) method to limit the number of rows to be processed as follows:

```
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database = "my_db",
    table_name = "my_table",
    transformation_ctx = "ds0")

applymapping1 = ApplyMapping.apply(
    frame = datasource0, 
    mappings = [("foo", "string", "bar", "string")],
    transformation_ctx = "am1")

truncated_df = applymapping1.toDF().take(1000)

datasink2 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame = DynamicFrame.fromDF(truncated_df, glueContext, "tdf"),
    connection_type = "s3", 
    ... )

job.commit()
```

This fails with the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jdf'
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Try converting data seperatly and then use dynamic frame name in datasink

Answer (score 1):

`df.take(1000)` returns a list.
Try using `applymapping1.toDF().limit(1000)`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).